# Need explanation for structure in C Programming

Tags: c, pointers, structure, nodes

```
struct  hello
{
  char id[5];
  int marks;
} a;
```

1)What is 'a' for?? Please explain with easy example, my lecturer is not good in explaining.

2)What if a is *a?? I know it's a pointer but when do we use it??

3)Is struct node a reserved word?? Also why do I see some structure has this ' struct node *x', I know it is a temporary storage,but why is it beside the word node instead of being inside the structure?? Like so:

```
struct node
{
  *x
}
```

4) What if I have structure inside the structure?? When do we use it and can I have example??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think all of these questions along with other questions will be answered if you read a standard text book on C Language.

Comment: [Please have a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29).

Answer (score 3):

The `a` is a normal variable, of the `struct hello` type.

And you will *never* see anything like

```
struct node
{
  *x
}
```

in a working program. Probably something like `struct node *x;` though.

Regarding the fields inside a structure, they can be declared like any other variable, so nesting structures inside structures works fine. A stupid example:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
};

struct bar
{
    struct foo f;

    /* If you're declaring a variable or (in this case) a structure
     * member, then you don't need to give a name to the structure
     */
    struct
    {
        int a;
    } g;
};
```

The `bar` structure now has two fields: `f` and `g`. Each of these is another structure containing a member named `a`.

Can be used like

```
struct bar bar;  /* Structure names and variable names can be the same */
bar.f.a = 5;
bar.g.a = 10;
```

Comment: so 

struct foo f; 

and 

struct foo
{

}f; 


are the same thing?? sorry new here, how do you grey out the area for codes in comment?

Comment: @user2421843 No they're not. `struct foo {} f;` creates an empty structure named `foo` and declares a variable `f` with using this empty structure. And if you already have a `struct foo` you will get a compilation error as you then try to define two structures of the same name.

Comment: sorry for those stupid questions, so 'foo' is just a name while the f is like declaring a variable like int f;??

Comment: @user2421843 Yes. `foo` is the name of the structure, to be used when declaring variables of this structure, while `f` is just an ordinary variable.

Answer (score 0):

1) `a` is a variable of type `struct hello`. Just like you can define

```
struct hello a;
```

if `struct hello` is already known.

You can also define it inline or even anonymously

```
struct {
    // some members
} a;
```

2) Just `*a` in this context is invalid. Any compiler will tell you that you cannot dereference a non-pointer type. `a` here is a type `struct hello`.

On the other hand `struct hello *a;` is valid and defines `a` as pointer to `struct hello`.

3) I am unaware of any standard library that reserves the keyword `node`. So defining a `struct node` should be perfectly valid.

As in 2) `struct node *x;` does not define temporary storage. It defines a pointer to `struct node` called `x`. It will initially have no memory assigned to it, but once it does you can reach it via `*x`.

Defining

```
struct node {
    *x;
};
```

is not valid C. Members of your struct have to be valid C types. Otherwise your compiler does not know how much memory the stuct takes up and how to reach those members.

But something like

```
struct node {
    char *x;
};
```

makes sense. It defines a `struct node` with a member `x` of type pinter to `char`.

4) Structures in structures are perfectly valid since you can give any valid C type to your structure members. Examples:

```
struct test {
    struct hello a; // using an already defined struct

    struct test * next; // using a pointer to own struct

    // or anonymous structs
    // normally used for readability of code
    struct {
        char member1;
        int member2;
    } anonymous_struct;

    // or even unions are allowed here
    // anonymous here
    union {
        int a;
        double b;
    } u;
} nested_struct;
```

These can now be accessed as nested structs:

```
nested_struct.a
nested_struct.next->a
nested_struct.anonymous_struct.member1
nested_struct.u.b
```

A live example would be `struct rusage` defined in `sys/resource.h` which has a nested `struct timeval` defined in `sys/time.h`. http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage

Please note that `x->a` is syntactically equivalent to `(*x).a` and can only be used if `x` is a pointer to struct.

Comment: can you explain to me why do we need the a; after the structure??
like for integer, we just need to do int a; ,why do we need a for structure ?? since we already declare the structure as hello??

Comment: @user2421843 `struct hello {...}` declares a type. Like `int` is a type. But in order to use an `int` you need to allocate an instance of `int` called `a`: `int a;`. Same with structs. `struct hello {...}` is the type, but in order to work with a `struct hello` you need to actually allocate one (or multiple) and call it whatever you want to, `a` is just a variable name. You can reuse the type `struct hello` for more then one variable. `struct hello a,b,c;` allocates three structs hello and assigns them the symbolic names `a`, `b` and  `c`. Equivalent in integers: `int a,b,c;`

Comment: sorry for asking all stupid question,then what's the 'hello' for?? why not just struct hello;? and why is it in some structure there isn't anything like 'a' at the end of it

Comment: @user2421843 Because if you don't name your structure (use it anonymously, which is allowed) then you can not use the same struct twice. `struct hello` gives the struct a name as a type. Once you have named it you can create instances `struct hello a; struct hello b;`. If you do not wish to name your struct type then you can define it anonymously `struct {...} a;` but you then can not pass it to another function or can have any other instance of the same type because you didn't name the type.